# Postfix Calculator Java -cannot resolve or is not a field

Tags: java, list, stack

I am encountering this error in the postfix calculator: the integerOperand cannot be resolved or is not a field. Below I have shown the main code, and the code from the IntegerOperand class file. How can I fix this? I am trying to call the add function from the IntegerOperand class.

```
public class IntegerOperand implements CalculatorOperand<IntegerOperand> {

    BigInteger value;

    IntegerOperand (BigInteger value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public IntegerOperand add (IntegerOperand that) {
        return new IntegerOperand(this.value.add(that.value));
    }
    public IntegerOperand subtract (IntegerOperand that) {
        return new IntegerOperand(this.value.subtract(that.value));
    }
    public IntegerOperand multiply (IntegerOperand that) {
        return new IntegerOperand(this.value.multiply(that.value));
    }

    public String toString () {
        return value.toString();
    }   
}


public void operation (OperationType operation) {

        T t1;
        T t2;
        if(stack.isEmpty())
        {   

              t2= stack.pop();
             t1= stack.pop();
            stack.push(t1.IntegerOperand.add(t2));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you are not calling the function correctly.

```
// You don't need the class name
//stack.push(t1.IntegerOperand.add(t2));
stack.push(t1.add(t2));
```

Second, you check if the stack is empty, then if it is, you try to `pop` from it. But you should check if the stack is *not* empty: `if (!stack.isEmpty())`. But since you then do 2 calls to `pop` you should instead check if there are at least 2 items in the stack.

```
if (stack.size() >= 2) {   
    t2 = stack.pop();
    t1 = stack.pop();
    stack.push(t1.add(t2));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, the function has to allow for stacks with less than 2 items in the stack, and the code cannot modify the stack if it contains less than 2 items. What should I consider in this case?

Comment: @ChloePupaiboon This code will not modify the stack if it has less than 2 items. For stacks with one item, you could add an `else` to handle that case.